# Login page when using a Zen's sub theme

Tags: users, theming

I've created a website based on a Drupal 7 Zen subtheme and now I would like to create a login page for the administrator. When I navigate to http://mysite.com/?q=user, I return to the main page as specified in the page.tpl.php file. I would like to have a manual login page, so I tried following the following tutorial: https://drupal.org/node/350634. My template.php looks like this:

```
function camuse_theme() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user_login'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'camuse') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-login',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
       'camuse_preprocess_user_login'
    ),
  );

  return $items;
}

function camuse_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
  $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome login form');
}
```

And my user-login.tpl.php file like this:

```
<p><?php print render($intro_text); ?></p>
<div class="camuse-user-login-form-wrapper">
<?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
</div>
```

However, when I navigate to http://mywebsite.com/?q=user, I still go to the home page. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, I've checked the names and everything seems fine. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the name of your template file to **user--login.tpl.php**, place this file in the **templates** folder of **camuse** theme and **clear all caches**.